# Asp.net Routing wrong MIME type for .css files served with UrlRoutingModule and PageBuildProvider

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-routing, url-routing, mime-types

I need to route request like:

- http://www.site.com/channel1/somestring
- http://www.site.com/channel1/otherstring
- http://www.site.com/channel2/anotherstring

to my default page: http://www.site.com/default.aspx page

for a web project that runs on .net 4.5, IIS Express with integrated pipeline.

**Routes:**

```
protected virtual void RegisterRoutes()
{
    RouteTable.Routes.MapPageRoute("AliasCss","{channel}/css/{*url}","~/css/{url}",
         false,null, new RouteValueDictionary { { "channel", "(channel1|channel2)"}});

    RouteTable.Routes.Ignore("{resource}.js");
    RouteTable.Routes.Ignore("{resource}.css");

    RouteTable.Routes.MapPageRoute("Alias", "{*url}", "~/Default.aspx", true, 
        new RouteValueDictionary { { "url", "Default.aspx" } }, 
        new RouteValueDictionary { { "url", "(channel1|channel2)" } });
}
```

It works great except for the css files

> Example: http://www.site.com/channel1/css/custom.css

that gives 404 error insted of serving the css files in http://www.site.com/css/custom.css

To solve this I needed to add a `PageBuildProvider` for making Asp.net serve static .css files and set `runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"`

**web.config relevant parts:**

```
<configuration>
    ...
    <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" >
            <buildProviders>
                <add extension=".css" type="System.Web.Compilation.PageBuildProvider" />
            </buildProviders>
        </compilation>
        <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" enableVersionHeader="false"  />
        ...
    </system.web>
    <system.webServer>
        <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="true" />
        <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
            <add name="UrlRoutingModule" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule,System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"  />
        </modules>
        ...
    </system.webServer>
    ...
</configuration>
```

Now .css files are correctly routed but **are served with wrong MIME type**:

> Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type
>   text/html

I tried to set the mimetype in web.config but with no luck:

```
<staticContent>
    <remove fileExtension=".css" />
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".css" mimeType="text/css; charset=UTF-8" />
</staticContent>
```